# cannot move imageView from one view to another view

Tags: objective-c, ios5, touch, imageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I use panGestureRecognizer to move imageView..

it can work in the parent view of this imageView.. and can move out of the parent view..

But when it come out of the parent view,  the panGestureReconizer cannot work..
it can't regconize the touch action for the imageView.. I don't know why...

and i want to find some ways to fix it out..

how to move imageView from parent view to another view....

before, I try to use touchBegan,touchMove..  I meet the same problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this property

```
      imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and now use the gesture..Hope it works now

Comment: and when I use touchMove to move imageView,  when this imageView come out to another view and then i touch it again ,it can't regconize it is a UIImageView class...    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if( [[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class] ]).........

Comment: oh...　i　see　　.when one view leave its parent view,it cannot touch 'it' again... so i create another imageview when i touch move ,and the new imageview is the subview of the bigger one..